# Is it possible to install Android app in Ubuntu phone?

Tags: installation, linux, apk

I was searching to have a convenient way of installing Android apps (APK file) in Ubuntu phone.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it's Android-independent; it's not about operating Android device, but Ubuntu phone. [ubuntu.se] should be the proper site to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. In fact, Canonical has [made a deliberate decision](http://www.androidauthority.com/ubuntu-smartphone-aunch-without-app-store-wont-support-android-apps-150903/) to NOT support an Android runtime in Ubuntu Phone.

However, now that Android apps are turned into native apps at install time (i.e., ART vs. DVM), it's not unthinkable that a third party could add support for this to Ubuntu Phone. I suggest you check out [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247973/will-android-apps-be-compatible-with-the-ubuntu-phone-os) at the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site.